# Text gradient with font awesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I just discovered [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) and I want to use it in my website.

The problem is, I want my font to be colored with a gradient.
I found [this code](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/) that works on standard text, but I can't make it work with a icon from Font Awesome

Here is what I tested:

```
<style>
    .big-icon {
        font-size: 72px;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eee), to(#333));
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
</style>

<span class="big-icon">
    Hello world
</span>
<i class="icon-beaker"></i>
<span class="big-icon">
    <i class="icon-beaker"></i>
</span>
```

And it displayed a "Hello world" with a gradient, the icon I want and then nothing...

Anyone have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Your font awesome link isn't working. Makes it pretty difficult to help for those of us not already familiar with it.

Comment: Why do you have two spans with class="big-icon"? Would it not work all inside one span?

Comment: It's for test purpose. First I test just the text gradient, next the font awesome and then both together.

Comment: Link to Font Awesome's website: https://fontawesome.com/

Answer (score 50):

Apply the styles directly on the icon.

```css
.fa-gradient {
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f00), to(#333));
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-3x fa-wrench fa-gradient"></i>
```

Answer (score 40):

Gave this a quick shot; the important thing to realize is that Font Awesome adds the actual icons via the ['before' pseudo-element](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-before):

```
[class^="icon-"]::before,
[class*=" icon-"]::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

.icon-beaker:before {
  content: "\f0c3";
}
```

To apply the gradient-effect to the icon, you have to target the pseudo-element which contains the icon – see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HGxMu/26/) for a working demonstration based upon your code:

```
.big-icon:before {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f00), to(#333));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: initial; /* reset Font Awesome's display:inline-block */
}​
```

---

**Edit:** The jsFiddle linked above does not work as expected anymore because the linked CSS-file that contains the "FontAwesome"-icons has moved; a working version using the [bootstrapcdn.com-hosted](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/#bootstrapcdn) version of FontAwesome v4.0.3 and updated FontAwesome-icon CSS class names is available at http://jsfiddle.net/HGxMu/55/