# FontAwesome gradient color in Next.js & React setup

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, font-awesome

I've been banging my head trying to add a gradient to the fontawesome icons in my page. No matter what I target, I cannot seem to get it working. I only manage to get a color in the .active icon by using the color property for either the a tag or the svg itself, which doesn't support gradient.

I have tried many solutions I found here and on other website using background-clip, but for some reason they don't seem to work. My website is using next.js, that's why the classes look funny like that, but I don't think it's affecting the styling of the icon.

How can I apply a gradient to the fontawesome component when it has the .active class?

This is the code for that element

```
const [video, setVideo] = useState({
    videoUrl:"resources/videos/video1.mp4",
    videoType: "video/mp4",
    videoTitle: "Explore ",
    videoMsg: "Express ",
    videoButton: "Features"
  });
const [numberState, setNumberState] = useState(1);

  const refillHook = (obj, i) => {
    setVideo({
      videoUrl: obj.link,
      videoType: obj.type,
      videoTitle: obj.title,
      videoMsg: obj.msg,
      videoButton: obj.button
    });
    setNumberState(i);
  }

  const videoItem = IconsVideos.map((video, i) => {
    return (
      <a onClick={() => refillHook(video, i)} className={numberState === i && `${Styles.active}`} key={i}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            className={`${Styles.iconLink}`}
            icon={faCoffee}
            size="2x"
          />
      </a> 
  )});

  return (
    <section className={`${Styles.stripe} ${Styles.stripeWithIcons} ${Styles.segment}`}>
        <div className={`${Styles.left} ${Styles.leftWithIcons}`}>
          <div className={`${Styles.leftInnerWithIcons}`}>
            <div className={`${Styles.iconsContainer}`}>
              <ul className={`${Styles.iconsList}`}>
                {videoItem}
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className={`${Styles.videosContainer}`}>
              <VideoPlayer src={video.videoUrl} type={video.videoType} />
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={`${Styles.right} ${Styles.rightWithIcons}`}>
        <div className={`${Styles.rightInner}`}>
          <h1 className={`${Styles.pageH1}`} >{video.videoTitle}</h1>
          <p className={`${Styles.pageP}`}>{video.videoMsg}</p>
          <PageButton buttonText={video.videoButton} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does this help, particularly the second answer. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732663/text-gradient-with-font-awesome

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I have tried that solution. Unfortunately, the icon disappears completely in that case. It's as if the background-clip doesn't work somehow

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this problem in the future - I finally found the solution. You can achieve this with masking.

In your HTML:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon className={styles.featureIcon} icon={["fas", "bolt"]} size="5x" mask={["fas", "square-full"]} />
```

In your CSS:

```
.featureIcon {
    background: rgb(226, 56, 56);
    background: linear-gradient(
        180deg,
        rgba(255, 185, 0, 1),
        rgba(247, 130, 0, 1),
        rgba(226, 56, 56, 1),
        rgba(151, 57, 153, 1),
        rgba(0, 156, 223, 1) 91%
    );
    color: var(--bg-color);
    border: black 2px;
}
```

Comment: What would the nuxt solution to this be i have the same component from fontawesome but your classes look very funny indeed and it confuses me a bit too much