# Linear gradient with iconify

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons

I'm using icons from [iconify](https://iconify.design/), and I want to color an icon with linear gradient color.
For some reason it's not working for me, I can only color the icon with regular one color, I already had a look at solutions given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732663/text-gradient-with-font-awesome) without success.

```css
.magiccolor {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#e24997), to(#2d2ed4));
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #e24997, #2d2ed4);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="magiccolor">linear-colored <span class="iconify" data-icon="ic:outline-local-offer"></span></h1>
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/2/2.1.2/iconify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe it's because the icon is an svg and not text?

Comment: Can I achieve something by adding the icon as a `background: url(url_of_the_icon.svg)`?

Comment: Probably not. SVGs aren't generally customisable as a background image

Comment: @user2401856 if you used `mask-image: url();` and base64 encode the SVG then you can do it

Comment: @evolutionxbox Is there anything I can do (maybe using transparent color for the svg and adding a mask background)? or should I use something other than iconify?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `mask-image` take a look at the solution below. If you hover over the the text/icon the gradient will change showing that the icon gradient matches the text gradient.

To get the base64 of the SVG I use this little tool https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/

I also set it up to use CSS Custom Properties (variables) so you can quickly override values with inline styles, shown on the second example.

Unfortunately due to the single/double quotes in the complex SVG string it is not possible to change `--iconBase64` variable using inline styles, I suggest setting up classes for this

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } body { font: 1px sans-serif; margin: 0; text-align: center } h1 { font-size: 3rem; margin: 0 } hr { margin-block: 1rem }

:root {
  --magicColor1: #e24997;
  --magicColor2: #2d2ed4;
  --magicAngle: 90deg;
}

.magiccolor, .magiccolor .base64icon::before {
  background-color: var(--magicColor1);
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--magicAngle), var(--magicColor1), var(--magicColor2), var(--magicColor1));
  background-size: 200%;
  background-position: top left;
  
  transition: background-position 1s ease-in-out;
}

.magiccolor:hover, .magiccolor:hover .base64icon::before { background-position: bottom right }

.magiccolor {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;

  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.magiccolor .base64icon {
  height: 1em; width: 1em;
  margin-left: .25em;
}

.magiccolor .base64icon.tag {
  --iconBase64: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' aria-hidden='true' role='img' class='iconify iconify--ic' width='1em' height='1em' preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid meet' viewBox='0 0 24 24' data-icon='ic:outline-local-offer'%3E%3Cpath fill='currentColor' d='m21.41 11.58l-9-9C12.05 2.22 11.55 2 11 2H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v7c0 .55.22 1.05.59 1.42l9 9c.36.36.86.58 1.41.58s1.05-.22 1.41-.59l7-7c.37-.36.59-.86.59-1.41s-.23-1.06-.59-1.42zM13 20.01L4 11V4h7v-.01l9 9l-7 7.02z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Ccircle cx='6.5' cy='6.5' r='1.5' fill='currentColor'%3E%3C/circle%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.magiccolor .base64icon.unicorn {
  --iconBase64: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 640 512'%3E%3Cpath d='M632 32L531.9 32c5.875-6.125 10.25-13.62 11.1-22.37C544.9 4.632 540.1 0 535.1 0h-120c-70.75 0-127.1 57.25-127.1 128c-63.88 0-104.2-36.76-127.7-90.26C156.1 30.22 146.7 30.03 143.2 37.46C133.5 58.03 128 80.81 128 105.1c0 66.1 51 133.1 128 147.8L256 256c-76.88 0-133.8-49.62-152.6-109C97.75 151.2 92.63 155.9 88 161.1L88 160C39.5 160 0 199.5 0 248v56c0 8.875 7.125 16 16 16L32 320c8.875 0 16-7.125 16-16l.0018-56c0-13.25 6.878-24.38 16.75-31.62c-.125 2.5-.7524 5-.7524 7.625c0 27.62 11.85 52.48 30.47 69.98l-25.74 68.89c-4.496 12.04-5.216 25.15-2.095 37.62l21.77 87.28C91.97 502 104.8 512 119.5 512h32.98c20.81 0 36.09-19.55 31.05-39.74l-21.26-85.39l23.78-63.61l102.1 22.34L288.1 480c0 17.67 14.33 32 32 32h32c17.6 0 32-14.4 32-32V318.2C403.7 297.1 416.1 270.5 416.1 240c0-.25-.105-.3828-.105-.6328V136.9L431.1 144l18.89 37.72c7.455 14.91 25.07 21.6 40.52 15.36l32.53-13.07c12.12-4.893 20.1-16.67 20.1-29.74l-.0246-70.98l92.44-36.66C643 42.26 639.9 32 632 32zM480 96c-8.875 0-16-7.125-16-16S471.1 64 479.1 64c8.875 0 16 7.125 16 16S488.9 96 480 96z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.magiccolor .base64icon::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  
  mask-image: var(--iconBase64); -webkit-mask-image: var(--iconBase64);
  mask-position: center right; -webkit-mask-position: center right;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat; -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-size: 1em; -webkit-mask-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="magiccolor">
  linear-colored <span class="base64icon tag"></span>
</h1>

<hr>

<h1 class="magiccolor" style="--magicColor1: green; --magicColor2: purple;">
  linear-colored <span class="base64icon unicorn"></span>
</h1>
```